# Modeling system objects for lookup table

Tags: database-design, tags, schema, lookup-tables, data-modeling

I am creating the object lookup table and not sure what exactly to call an object. This is a social network. I know items like photo, video, status etc are objects but what about account settings, mail folders, mail attachments, error messages, etc? Some things like "Tags" is that an object by itself or only when we combine it with Photo tag, Video tag, Peopletag, etc?

Do we model all objects 1 to 1 with system or have parent objects and child objects for lookup purposes?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to a database schema, you should think of it like this.

If two errors are semantically the same (i.e., "foo" == "foo"), then it can be turned into a lookup table. If two names are semantically not the same, even if they have the same value (i.e., "john" == "john" but the persons are different), then you shouldn't use a lookup table.

For things like tags, you might want to use a lookup table, but if they will be entered by the user, it is probably better to keep them as strings in the database. Lookup tables are best used for large objects (to reduce storage) or values that don't change often. There are exceptions to this, but it's a good rule of thumb.

Does this make sense?

Erick

Comment: The lookup table is only to store the objects list the system has, not the actual user content of the objects. Those are all stored in their seperate tables like user_photos, user_videos etc. But they all need to link to a parent object table so I can pull in the Analytics for the user objects. So object lookup table will only have object_id & object. But I am unsure how indepth the objects should go, because photo is an object, but photo tag can be an object, photo comment can be an object, photo recommendation can be an object. Or do we model as Comment, Photo, Recommendation are separate?

Comment: Also how else do we store data which changes a lot if we dont use lookup tables and that data is required to be fixed list items of site? I thought all restricted user input should be lookup based whether it changes or doesnt change?